# Authorization Model: Context of Role?

Tags: security, authorization, claims-based-identity, abac, role-based-access-control

I am currently attempting to design an Authorization Model that has the following components:

Privileges - an action that can either be granted or denied to a user/group

Roles - a collection of privileges; roles can be associated with a user or group

Security Objects - the entity to which security is applied

Object Owners - the owner of a security object

Statuses - an attribute that represents the state of a security object

Users - standard consumer of the service; can be denied or granted access to do things

Groups - a collection of users sharing a common thing; roles can be assigned to groups; privileges can be assigned to groups

My questions is as follows: Is there a way to properly model the context of a role with the current components that I presented above?

For instance, let's say i have the current authorization statement:

```
Tim can see Mary's profile information because Tim is Mary's friend.
```

I can dissect this statement into the model components:

```
User: Tim
Security Object: profile information
Object Owner: Mary
Privilege: view
Role: friend
Group: N/A?
Status: N/A
```

One thing that this dissection does not attribute is that Tim is a friend **of Mary**

Is there a component that I can add to this model that will capture this context ("of Mary"), or is there a way I can re-represent the privilege statement using my pre-existing auth model components? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should not attempt to implement a new authorization model. There is already a good model called attribute-based access control (or ABAC - see the SO tag [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) and [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)).

ABAC is an authorization model that:

- is defined by NIST, the National Institute of Standards and Technology, the very same organization that defines RBAC (role-based access control)
- uses attributes to define access control logic. Attributes

  - are a key-value pair e.g. role == manager
  - can be multi-valued e.g. citizenship = Canadian, Swedish
  - can describe anything e.g. the requesting user, the targeted object, the action, relationships, time, location...
- uses policies to define access control logic. These policies

  - are written in XACML ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml))
  - use attributes to define the access control scope
- enables externalized authorization: essentially your authorization logic is decoupled from your business logic. This is great because you can develop your apps independently of your security.

Let's take your example:

> Tim can see Mary's profile information because Tim is Mary's friend.

The authorization requirement would therefore be:

```
A user can view another user's profile if both users are friends.
```

In ABAC, you have to identify your attributes. You do this in your question which is great though your analysis is role-biased. Let's take it again. The attributes I see are:

- an action id (view)
- a resource type (user profile)
- a friend list (Tim's friend list)
- a profile owner (Mary)

With these attributes, I can rewrite your requirement in a broken-down way:

```
A user can do the action actionId==view on a resource of type==user profile if profile.owner is in the user's friend list.
```

You can then use ALFA ([alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa)) to implement the policy in [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)) and then XACML.

```java
namespace com.axiomatics{
    /**
     * A user can view another user's profile...
     */
    policy viewProfile{
        target clause actionId=="view" and resourceType=="user profile"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Allow if both users are friends.
         */
        rule allowIfFriends{
            condition stringIsIn(stringOneAndOnly(subjectId), friendList)
            permit
        }
    }
}
```

The XACML outcome (in XML) is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.viewProfile"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description>A user can view another user's profile...</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">view</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:Match>
                <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">user profile</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="resourceType"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
        </xacml3:AnyOf>
    </xacml3:Target>
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.viewProfile.allowIfFriends">
        <xacml3:Description>Allow if both users are friends.</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:Target />
        <xacml3:Condition>
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in" >
                <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only" >
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:Apply>
                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                    AttributeId="friendList"
                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                    MustBePresent="false"
                />
            </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Condition>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach that I have not considered. Thank you for sharing this with me.

In conjunction with this model, I have found an article on a different model, that may also satisfy my requirements. It's called ReBAC (Relationship Based Access Control)

http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~pwlfong/Pub/codaspy2011.pdf

Now it's just a matter of seeing for my purposes if ABAC or ReBAC will work better for my application.

Thanks again.